# Type of neural net for estimating Euclidean color distance?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I'd like to train a neural net to return a normalized color distance between two RGB pixels trained [at first] on a simple Euclidean distance with each color component being 0-255. there are 6 inputs (2 pixels x R,G,B components) and 1 output (a normalized 0-1 color distance). or should there be 48 binary inputs (2 pixels x 24 bits per px)?

the training set will probably consist of 1k - 10k randomly generated pixel pairs and their computed distances. i'm open to creating/chaining several simple nets rather than training one perfect one. e.g. splitting each by hue1/hue2 combo that can be cheaply determined in advance.

i'm new to ML and was hoping to get some advice since my intuition is basically zero for what type of net i need and ballpark for what the topology and params should be.

most supervised neural nets seem to do classification into buckets, but i don't quite understand how to get a net to predict a value that is not just one out of several categories. can i still use a simple feed-forward network for this task or something different?

thanks for any advice!

Comment: I'm confused as to what you are aiming to do.  You are just trying to find some pattern between similar color types and their distances? If this is the case a simple neural network would be sufficient, but I'm unsure what your expected output would want to be.

Comment: i would like it to predict the distance (0-1) between two rgb colors.

Comment: I might be slightly confused, but if you take two colours and treat them each as a vector: {(150, 255, 76), (22, 66, 112)}, why not just find the euclidean distance mathematically? Or are you trying to just teach a neural net to do that itself? If so, you should divide each component value by 255 to normalize them. Then you would use the 6 input neuron approach with one output representing the normalised distance. I can't imagine binary inputs being the best idea - at least not worth while testing at this stage.

Comment: Euclidean distance on raw RGB is just a litmus test. in reality this is far from being perceptually accurate. the ultimate goal is to teach a net to do eucledian distance on rgb in the CIECAM02-UCS (Jab) color space, and the math to convert from RGB->Jab is quite expensive. if i can feed the original rgb through a net (or several) that can efficiently predict ballpark Jab components, that would be ideal.